# Make and use temporary attribute for a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4.1

The form has an option to select the table column name. I want to input text into the table column selected by the form. To do this I am trying to make temporary attributes that the form can use to store the value and examine in the create method. Then assign the text to the correct column, then save.

Controller:

```
def new
  @word = Word.new
  @language = Word.new(params[:language])
  @translation = Word.new(params[:translation])
  @language_options = Word.column_names
end

def create
  @word = Word.new(word_params)
  if @language == "arabic"
    @word.arabic == @translation
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @word.save
      format.html { redirect_to @word, notice: 'Word was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @word }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @word.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@word) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'English String' %>

    <%= f.input :language, collection: @language_options %>

    <%= f.input :translation, placeholder: 'Translated String' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `language' for #<Word:0x007f6116b1bcb8>
```

Which is because there is not a language attribute for the form to use. So I was trying to make a temporary one in the controller new().

Is there a way to do this or do I have to make :language and :translation in a database table to reference in the form?

Comment: Use simple input helpers for that values. Like `text_field` or `select`.

Comment: Also in method `create` `@language` and `@translation` do not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Virtual Attribute**

You *may* benefit from using an [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) in your model

This creates a *virtual attribute* which works the same as the "real" attributes in your model:

```
#app/models/word.rb
Class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :column_name
end
```

This will allow you to assign values to this attribute which won't be saved into the db, which sounds like what you want:

```
#app/views/words/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for(@word) do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :column_name do %>
          <%= f.select :column_name, @language_options %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When you submit this form, it will then give you the `column_name` attribute to edit:

```
#app/controllers/words_controller.rb
Class WordsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      # ... you'll have "column_name" attribute available
   end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, yes this is what I want. I will play with this first before accepting as answer. +1